# How can I list ALL the remotes in the new git experience for VS2022

Tags: git, visual-studio

I seem to not be able to fetch from the upstream repo because it is not visible in the 'Manage Branches' window in VS2022:
[image]

It is clearly set up under Git Repo settings but still, I can't issue any command against it from VS2022:

[image]

Any ideas as to why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this issue still happens with the VS2022 version 17.3.3. The workaround is install the [Git Extensions](https://gitextensions.github.io/) and add the remote from there instead from VS2022. After added the remote it will create a folder for the remote on `\.git\logs\refs\remotes` and `\.git\refs\remotes` which the VS2022 doesn't do anymore. From now the remote will also be showing in the VS2022 by opening the `Git Repository` window.